# Hexadecimal string with float number to float

Tags: python-3.x

Iam working in python 3.6
I receive from serial comunication an string '3F8E353F'. This is a float number 1.111. How can I convert this string to a float number?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you show how those two numbers are equal? `1.111.hex()` returns `0x1.1c6a7ef9db22dp+0`

Comment: Could you describe how that input value is equal to `1.111`?

Comment: Float number with 32 bits. bit31 signed. bits 30 to 23 exponent bits 22 to 0 mantisa. signed*2^(exponent-127)*(1+mantisa/2^23) = 2^0*(1.11099994)

Comment: I get this string from a Texas Instruments DSP. I can make a function to convert string may be python has a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yes.  Since this is 32-bits, unpack it into an `int` first then:

```
x='3F8E353F'
struct.unpack('f',struct.pack('i',int(x,16)))
```

On my system this gives:

```
>>> x='3F8E353F'
>>> struct.unpack('f',struct.pack('i',int(x,16)))
(1.1109999418258667,)
>>>
```

Very close to the expected value.  However, this can give 'backwards' results based on the 'endianness' of bytes in your system.  Some systems store their bytes least significant byte first, others most significant byte first.  See [this reference page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) for the descriptors to format based on byte order.

Comment: with float.fromhex('3F8E353F') I get 1066284351.0 instead of 1.111.

Comment: If memory serves the struct.unpack documentation tells how to overcome this.  I'm looking now also, been awhile since I saw this error

Comment: edited my answer to show documentation for byte order between different system.

Answer (score 0):

I used `struct.unpack('f',struct.pack('i',int(x,16)))` to convert Hex value to float but for negative value I am getting below error

> struct.error: argument out of range

To resolve this I used below code which converts Hex (0xc395aa3d) to float value (-299.33). It works for both positive as well for negative value.

```
x = 0xc395aa3d
struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('I', int(x,16) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use *bytes.fromhex()*

```
import struct
hexstring = '3F8E353F'
struct.unpack('!f', bytes.fromhex(hexstring))[0] 
#answer:1.1109999418258667
```

Note: The form '!' is available for those poor souls who claim they can’t remember whether network byte order is big-endian or little-endian (from [struct docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)).